# Firing intent to ignore battery optimization not working in Ticwatch

Tags: android, wear-os, wakelock

I need to maintain a persistent internet connection for my Wear OS app and as the first step, I am requesting the `ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` permission in my background **service** (before requesting WiFi and partial Wake Locks). However, this intent is not being displayed on the app.

My code in a background service:

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Attempting to ignore battery optimizations...");

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        String packageName = getPackageName();
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

In Android manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>`

I am using [Mobvoi Ticwatch E](https://www.mobvoi.com/us/pages/ticwatche2) which--it would seem--does not app an option to whitelist apps. As well, in the app settings, the option to "Modify system permission" is greyed out.

Please help!

Comment: You don't need to ignore battery optimizations to have a persistent internet connection - that's what a foreground service is for.

Comment: Actually, I need a background service running, even when the user is interacting with other apps on the watch. When a message comes, a notification is displayed.

Comment: Did you ever get any solution this this?

Comment: Got the same issue with an app that requires BOOT_COMPLETED event, however it's battery optimized and won't start on watch boot. Trying to request ignore battery optimizations leads to a FakeSettingsActivity that shows nothing :( Did anyone found a solution?